# Capture information on images generated by ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick

I'm considering using ImageMagick to extract images from individual pages from a PDF file. How can I capture the names of the files getting generated by it? It seems that the `-verbose` option includes information on the files getting generated, but is that a reliable way of gathering that? Any other alternatives?

Comment: Not sure I understand this... if you have `FreddyFrog.pdf` and you use IM `convert` to create `PeppaPig.jpg`, what is it that you want to capture? You already have the input files and output files in your filesystem. Sorry if I am being stupid.

Comment: If I have `FreddyFrog.pdf`, it might generate `FreddyFrog[1].png`, `FreddyFrog[2].png`, until `FreddyFrog[n].png`. I don't know up front how many pages it has. ImageMagick knows how many it generated. I want to invoke the command, and then hopefully capture something on stdout to know how many it generated, and what the names of the files were.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to do, I think you have at least 3 options...

**Option 1**

If you want to know the number of pages up front, *a priori*, you can get ImageMagick to tell you like this:

```
identify -format %n FreddyFrog.pdf
8
```

or if you want it in a variable,

```
pages=$(identify -format %n FreddyFrog.pdf)
echo $pages
8
```

**Option 2**

You can tell ImageMagick how to format the names of the output files, like this, where the `%04d` says to use 4 digits and front-pad with zeroes:

```
convert -density 72 FreddyFrog.pdf FreddyFrog-%04d.tif
```

Then you will automatically know the names of the output files.

```
ls FreddyFrog-*
FreddyFrog-0000.tif FreddyFrog-0003.tif FreddyFrog-0006.tif
FreddyFrog-0001.tif FreddyFrog-0004.tif FreddyFrog-0007.tif
FreddyFrog-0002.tif FreddyFrog-0005.tif
```

**Option 3**

You can use the shell to *draw a line in the sand* before you convert the files and then find everything newer afterwards:

```
> before                                                    # or "touch before" if you prefer
convert FreddyFrog.....                                     # strut your IM stuff
for f in *; do [[ "$f" -nt before ]] && echo $f; done       # list files newer than line in sand
rm before                                                   # clean up
```

rm before

Comment: How did you get on with this?